# Using static method from generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I have problem as above. My code:

```
public abstract class BaseFactory<T> where T: class
{
    protected static dbModelContainer context = new dbModelContainer();

    public static int UpdateDataBase_static()
    {
        return context.SaveChanges();
    }
 }
```

and my question is how can I call

```
BaseFactory.UpdateDataBase_static();
```

instead of:

```
BaseFactory<SomeClass>.UpdateDataBase_static();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: do you mean use it non generically, or do you mean have the compiler infer T from the context

Comment: You really can't do this.  Either you need to put the method in a non-generic class, or you need to provide a type when you call it.  You can't have it both ways.

Comment: Why do you have a static context to begin with?  If this is is an EF context, they should be created when you need it and disposed of when you're done.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, because there is no such method. The closest is to have a non-generic base that the generic class inherits from. Then you can have a method there that doesn't depend on the parameterising type.

Answer (score 2):

To call `BaseFactory.UpdateDataBase_static();` you need a class `BaseFactory`. Inherite the generic `BaseFactory<T>` from it.

```
public abstract class BaseFactory
{
    protected static dbModelContainer context = new dbModelContainer();

    public static int UpdateDataBase_static()
    {
        return context.SaveChanges();
    }
 }

public abstract class BaseFactory<T>:BaseFactory where T: class
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't.

You always need to supply the generic type arguments when accessing a class, even though you aren't using that type argument in your method.  Since you *don't* actually use the generic type in the method it means you could move that method out of that class, and into one that isn't generic, but for as long as it's in that class you'll need to supply the generic argument.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do exactly what you're asking, but since the method doesn't use `T` at all, you can just use `BaseFactory<object>.UpdateDataBase_static();` without specifying any particular class.

But as an editorial comment, in general a method in a generic class that never uses the generic parameter probably shouldn't be there.