# C#: How do I call non-generic static method in generic class without specifying generic type?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, generics

So I have, let's say, some class that requires generic type as a parameter:

```
public class SomeClass<GType> { }
```

And there I have a static method that doesn't interact with this generic type in any way:

```
public static void Method() { }
```

The problem is, when I try to call this method, it requires me to specify this generic type. I could, in fact, put there any type and that would work, but it just doesn't seem quite right, does it?

Comment: Possibly this post is a duplicate of the next one: [Using static method from generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958494/using-static-method-from-generic-class). Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public static void DoSomething()
    {

    }
}

public class SomeClass<GType> : SomeClass
{
    public void DoAnotherThing<GType>()
    {

    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SomeClass.DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Yeah okay, that's kind of a workaround

Comment: I think if you want to call method on generic class without specify generic type , this seems design problem .

Comment: But I guess that's fine as a method that doesn't need a generic type of its class is in theory supposed to do something else so... Thanks.